# otrs gives an "Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"

Tags: dpkg, otrs

I installed [`otrs`](http://www.otrs.com/nl/) like so:

```
sudo apt-get install otrs
```

And in the end it gave me this error below.

```
Setting otrs2 (3.1.7 + dfsg1-5) ...
dbconfig-common: writing config to / etc/dbconfig-common/otrs2.conf
Replacing config file / etc / OTRS / database.pm with new version
Already perl module enabled
Already rewrite module enabled
  * Reloading web server config apache2: Could not reliably determining the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
                                                                                                                                            [OK]
DBI connect ('database = OTRS, host = localhost, port = 3306;', 'OTRS', ...) failed: Access denied for user'' @ 'localhost' to database 'OTRS' at / usr / share / OTRS / Kernel / System / DB.pm line 256
ERROR: OTRS-otrs.RebuildConfig.pl-10 Perl: 5.14.2 OS: linux Time: Wed March 13 2013 12:01:17

  Message: Access denied for user'' @ 'localhost' to database 'OTRS'

  Traceback (7612):
    Module: Kernel :: System :: DB :: new (v1.144.2.1) Line: 227
    Module:. / Bin / otrs.RebuildConfig.pl (v1.14) Line: 55

Got no DBObject! at / usr / share / OTRS / Kernel / System / SysConfig.pm line 103.
dpkg: error processing otrs2 (- configure):
  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255 back
Errors were encountered while processing:
  otrs2
E: Sub-process / usr / bin / dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have a dutch Ubuntu the error above I copy/paste it in Google translater

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with the Ubuntu package. While the OTRS debian package is pretty well maintained, the Ubuntu package (which is derived from the Debian package) is broken and no-one really seems to care about it. See all bug reports here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/otrs2

So if you want to install OTRS from a package manager, choose Debian, or if you want to install OTRS on Ubuntu, please look at this procedure:

http://wiki.otterhub.org/index.php?title=Installation_on_Ubuntu_Lucid_Lynx_(10.4)

(yeah I know it is written for Ubuntu 10.04 and OTRS 3.0.x but the procedure is really very much the same)